# Real Time vs Turn Based (XNA)

Tags: xna, multiplayer

What is a more difficult type of game to develop on XNA: A Real Time multiplayer game or a Turn Based multiplayer game? (not client server or peer to peer, just in general)

Any links to articles would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: -1 Which is more difficult is not a constructive question. There are far too many variables to reasonably answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think any of them are any more harder than the other, both of them are hard beacuse it´s multiplayer.

If you just sit down and carefully plan all your design you will mostlikley endup with a overall good devlopment on what ever game you do ( realtime or turnbased ).